# Linked List Structure Push and Pop

Tags: c++, c

I'm struggling regarding a program that ask user to enter numbers and it will only stop asking user to enter number if user enters `0`.

however I can't seem to place the value of the 2nd number entered to `Data2`,

how do we PUSH number into `data` and `data2` by the inputted numbers of the user and then sum it up Data + data2 and print sum ?

for example, user enters `1,2,0`

Comment: Sorry I've had enough homebrew linked lists for today. Why is everyone so averse to using std::list which works?

Comment: Could be homework, could be experimentation

Comment: I read two or three times :( didn't get you clearly.

Comment: for example user entered 1 2 0, then 1 should be Pushed in Data1 and 2 should be pushed in Data2, my program is storing both 1 value on data1 and data2.. i don't know how to separate them and assign to data1 and data2 separately. so the variable should contain data1=1 and data2=2

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is with the input, not with the list.

Try input `1 2 0` rather than `1,2,0` and you will find it works just fine. (you won't get output `1 + 2 = 3` because that isn't what you output. Rather, you get `The sum of Popped item is 3`.

BTW, the first occurrence of `while ( Num !=0)` uses Num before it is initialized. If the value happens to be 0, then the program won't work. Try changing `int Num;` at the top of `main()` to be `int Num=99;`

Comment: Also, `Data2` is not needed, and can be deleted.

Comment: my code is for that output, but i'm trying to Input Numbers like 1 2 0, and 1 should be pushed in Data1 and 2 should be Pushed inside Data2, and prints out a result of 3 once it's POPPED. but i can't seem to seperate 1 and 2 and place them to data1 and data2, instead the data 1 contains 1 and data2 contains 1 still..

Comment: But then it won't work for 3, 4, 5 or 999 numbers. You said you wanted the program to "enter numbers and it will only stop asking user to enter number if user enters 0."

Comment: Did you try is with input `1 2 0`? The program is working, it just needs tidying up to get rid of `Data2`, and to get the input to accept commas, if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `push` with the a single `num`,and it gets stored onto `NewNode` twice,instead of the second integer.

You must be calling the `push` with the integers for `data1` and `data2` by using something like

```
while (1)
{
        scanf("%d", &Num1);
        scanf("%d", &Num2);
        if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0)
              break;
        Push(Top, Num1,num2); //execute the Push Function

}
```

And inside `push`

```
void Push(StackPointer &Top, int Num1,int num2)
{ 
 StackPointer NewNode;
 NewNode=(StackPointer)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 NewNode->Data = Num1;
 NewNode->Data2 =Num2;
 NewNode->Link = Top;
 Top = NewNode;
}
```

Comment: scanf("%d", &Num1);
scanf("%d", &Num2);
this line will store the number you entered on both variable, for example you inputed 1, 2, it will store 1 in Num1 and Num2 still

Comment: yeah,but you pass only num1 to push and place that in data1 and data2,and the next push enters data into the next node

Comment: by usin this scanf("%d", &Num1); scanf("%d", &Num2);whichever num you enter will be stored in num1 and num2...